# ¿Como redireccionar a otra página de forma segura en Java?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, crud

Tengo un recurso (página web) en el que quiero ingresar de forma mediante un Servlet. Pero el problema es que ese recurso, se puede ingresar simplemente escribiendo en la barra de direcciones del navegador.

En el Servlet, el metodo POST es invocado y luego este tiene dos objetos (`response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY)` y  `response.setHeader("Location", "registro.html")`) que utilizo para tratar de redireccionar la página de forma segura, pero no funciona. Aun puedo seguir accediendo al recurso de forma insegura.

¿Hay alguna librería  que se pueda utilizar?

Acá esta el Servlet con el que intento hacer la redirección de forma segura:

```
try {

 String disp = "select disponibilidad from T_tiphab where tipo=? and codHotel=?";
 String precio = "SELECT SUM( ?  * (select precio from T_tiphab where tipo= ? and codHotel= ?) ) AS total";
 if (reserva.disponibilidad(disp) > 0) {
  out.print("$ " + reserva.disponibilidad(precio));
  response.setStatus(response.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
  response.setHeader("Location", "registro.html");
 } else {
  out.print("No hay disponibilidad");
 }
```

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Depende un poco del grado de seguridad que deseas implementar para tu aplicación en general.

Si lo que deseas es que solo se acceda a la pagina una vez que se ha realizado un proceso de autenticación (login) y solo si el usuario logeado cuenta con la autorización para ver el recurso, entonces puedes usar Spring-Security o Apache Shiro.

Con Spring Security puedes indicar mediante configuración que cierto recurso solo puede ser accedido por peticiones POST y no GET o que solo se puede trabajar con el recurso utilizando https o que las peticiones que vengan por el puerto inseguro pasen al puerto seguro entre otras muchas cosas.

Si tu proyecto ya tiene Spring entonces Spring Security pudiera integrarse de forma más natural a tu desarrollo.

Ahora bien si lo que tienes es un proyecto pequeño y más escolar que profesional puedes apoyarte únicamente de la Sesión del usuario (clase HttpSession cuya instancia puedes obtener del metodo getSession con que cuenta la clase HttpServler).

A la Sesion le puedes agregar atributos con los datos del usuario que ha realizado el login y con los permisos que cuente el mismo, luego en cada invocación a un recurso puedes recuperar de la sesion el atributo agregado para verificar si con sus permisos puede trabajar con el recurso solicitado.

Te dejo las ligas al proyecto Spring Security:

https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/

Y al proyecto Apache Shiro:

https://shiro.apache.org/

Para ver si se acomodan a lo que necesitas.