# Servlet: sendRedirect() no fuciona cuando se consulta desde la barra del navegador

Tags: java, html, netbeans, rest, servlets

Tengo un `Servlet` que responde con un `sendRedirect()` cuando hay una consulta `GET` por parte del navegador. En caso de que la haya  se redirige al usuario a un segundo `Form`. 
 El problema esta con la seguridad de la aplicación. Si ingreso en la barra del navegador la dirección del segundo `Form`(`localhost:8080/aplicacion/secondForm.html`) logra evitar cumplir con la condición.

Muchas Gracias.

Este es el codigo del `Servlet`:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String      texto = request.getReader().readLine();

    if (request.getMethod() == "GET"){
        response.sendRedirect("secondForm.html");
    } else {
        out.print("Formulario Incompleto");
           }
```

Comment: Iba a responder(de hecho he respondido), pero veo que muchas respuestas las dejas sin marcar como correctas, ni comentar los problemas, así que he borrado la respuesta. Y en todo caso mi respuesta va en la línea de la respuesta que ignoraste en esta otra pregunta que ya hiciste(https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163866/como-redireccionar-a-otra-p%c3%a1gina-de-forma-segura-en-java)

Comment: Gracias.Si. Lo que pasa es que generalmente lo resuelvo por mi mismo. Ninguna respuesta me ha  ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

> Si ingreso en la barra del navegador la dirección del segundo Form(localhost:8080/aplicacion/secondForm.html) logra evitar cumplir con la condición.

Efectivamente.

`sendRedirect` lo único que hace es decirle al navegador "los datos que me has pedido en `/firstForm.html` los tienes que buscar haciendo una nueva petición a `/secondForm.html`". El navegador hace la nueva petición automáticamente y el servidor web responde.

Pero es simplemente una petición `HTTP GET /secondForm.html`, que para el servidor es igual venga de una redirección o no.

Imagina que en vez de peticiones hay llamadas de teléfono. Llamas al teléfono 111111 y si tienes el password, te dicen que lo que buscas te lo darán en el teléfono 222222. Pero una llamada al teléfono 222222 funciona aunque no hayas llamado antes al 111111.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto (bueno, hay más pero para empezar mira éstas):

- JAAS, el API de Java de seguridad de servidor de aplicaciones. La configuración dependerá del servidor web que uses (no, netbeans no es un servidor web).
- En tu servlet defines alguna información para detectar que el usuario ha pasado la autenticación (por ejemplo, un atributo en la `session` o un token temporal en la URL a la que rediriges) y defines un `HttpFilter` que protege el recurso privado y que comprueba dicha información.